# Fetch data from database in JSON using AngularJS and display it to the textbox

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I am new to AngularJS. I just want to fetch data from my database and store it on the textbox.

Here's my code:

```
$scope.sample = function(){
    $http.post('query?action=get',{

    })
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.info = response;
    })
    .catch(function(response){
        alert("error");
     });
};
 // call the function
 $scope.sample();
```

and in PHP:

```
$action = $_GET['action'];

if($action == 'get'){

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tableSomething";
   $sql_res = $con->query($sql);
   $data = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_res)){
         $data[] = $row;
   }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

and in my HTML File

```
<input type="text" ng-model="info.firstname" >
```

Tell me where I got mistake. Thanks!

Comment: what you get in `response`?

Comment: How to get the message in response sir? I tried `alert(response.data);` but it seems not working, I mean no alert was showing. @Curiousdev

Comment: Just applying some debugging skills put a debug on `$scope.info = response;` check debug hit this `then` function or not because rest of the things seems like fine

Comment: I already did that sir. I added this inside .then and .catch `console.log('response')` but nothing shows on my console, no errors and no messages

Comment: what print in console is your then function hit?

Comment: I think problem in You use $http.post for call service and in service you use $_GET['action'];

Comment: I call the `$scope.sample();`

Comment: I got a message like this in my console; `success: [object object]` when I add this inside my `.then` `console.log("success: " + $scope.info);`

Comment: just try to `console.log($scope.info)` it's give object

Comment: yes, it gives me an object. What should I do? @bipinpatel

Comment: can you paste your json here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `response` is an object.

First of all your server request is a GET and not a POST.

So change `$http.post('query?action=get',{` with `$http.get('query?action=get',{`

If there are no other code issues you get `data` of `response`.

Replace `$scope.info = response;` with `$scope.info = response.data;`

Your example code lacks the definition of `$scope`, so I can not test it fully.

I hope I have solved your problem

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Ok. AngularJS is too much insightful.

It sees that the response content has a JSON structure and returns it as an object.

Let stringify:

```
.then(function(response){
        $scope.info = JSON.stringify(response);
    })
```

and change your

`<input type="text" ng-model="info.firstname" >`

to

`<input type="text" ng-model="info" >`

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0011k50e/1/) a JSFiddle Example

Comment: I already did that sir, but how to call the data and display it on a textbox? @Oscar Zarrus

Comment: I tried displaying in a paragraph tag the `{{info}}` and it successfully display the data in json format text, however when I put it inside `ng-model="info"` it only gives me a result of `[object object]` and when I try to add this `ng-model="info.firstname"` there was no result given. Why?